# Android RecyclerView adapter change notifications, DiffUtil and adding items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm seeing some weird issues and would appreciate some help getting to the bottom of this.

The issue seems to be directly related to notifying adapter about data changes and how I set the underlying data. For example:

```
    mItems.clear();
    mItems.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    // takes about 0.6 seconds to start onBind() for a list with 350ish items
```

takes a lot longer to reach the `onBindViewHolder()` after the `notifyDataSetChanged()`, than for example the following:

```
    mItems = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    // takes negligible amout of time
```

So it's probably to do with how what adapter considers as data change? As in de-referencing the list object and assigning it a reference to a new one gets processed faster? But why?

This is also noticeable with `DiffUtil`. I've got the following update method:

```
    if (getItems() != null && getItems().size() > 0) {
        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil
                .calculateDiff(new MyClipsDiffUtil(getItems(), items));
        mItems.clear();
        Collections.addAll(items);
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
```

The above code would run slower than using `mItems = items;` instead of `clear` and `addAll`. Also I'm using the same list so there is no diff between the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

The change notification doesn't know anything about the data set itself.

The difference is in the part before. Assigning a reference doesn't have any impact at all. Calling `clear()` and `addAll()` has a higher complexity and thus runs longer. But this strongly depends on the type of the `List` your actually using.